# Dropdown within datatables won't vertically align

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I have a dropdown within a datatables table that is created dynamically - i have amended the bootstrap css so that the vertical alignment of the table is set to **middle** but the dropdown is still showing as top

```
.table > thead > tr > th,
.table > tbody > tr > th,
.table > tfoot > tr > th,
.table > thead > tr > td,
.table > tbody > tr > td,
.table > tfoot > tr > td
{
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

see my jsbin [here](http://live.datatables.net/dukuveno/1/)

(if you enter any text then **Add Instruction** then click on the **Load Copied Data** button)

Many thanks in advance

**Update**: it was the *form-group* class on a parent div that had the setting: margin-bottom: 15px

I created a new class to override that setting margin-bottom to 0px

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: thanks @Paulie_D - i've added code to my question now

Comment: Can we reproduce the problem based on the supplied code now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select parent div has a **.form-group** class, which has style **margin-bottom:15px;**

You can add **margin-top:15px;** to **.form-group** in your css or set **margin:0px;**

Comment: thanks - if I do that, it messes up other parts of my page - is there a way to override the form-group margin-bottom from within input-xs or by adding another class?

Comment: it's ok, I added a new class form-group-nomargin and it does override - thanks for the point in the right direction! :)

Comment: Leddy, I think, the better way is add class to table-parent, and then set in css

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't actually align top. The parent `div` simply has a Bootstrap CSS:

```
.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your css **select.input-xs** just add **margin-top: 15px;** it will properly align your dropdown.